# How to get list of git tags for a repository in AWS CodeCommit? (not AWS resource tags)

Tags: amazon-web-services, git, aws-cli, aws-codecommit

How can I get list of git tags of a repository in AWS CodeCommit?

I am able to get list of branches with:

```
aws codecommit list-branches --repository-name MY_REPO_NAME
```

Is there something similar for git tags?

**PS**:

- I tried [`list-tags-for-resource`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/how-to-tag-repository-list.html) but this is another thing.
- I am trying to get tags from more than 100 repositories in my account. So *I want to avoid* cloning 100+ repositories and do `git ls-remote --tags origin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would not need to clone the repository if you have the access set probably looping through the repository and using below command will give you all the tags

`git ls-remote --refs --tags https://git-codecommit.$region.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/xxrepo-namexx`

Comment: Thank you I did not know I can call git by passing the full repository address!. 
I tried with `git ls-remote --refs --tags codecommit::ap-northeast-1://my-repo-here` and it worked!